# How to disable the addition of flattened source data to fields in Elasticsearch Kibana 7.16.3

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We are using Elasticsearch, Kibana version 7.16.3. Previously we were using version 7.10.x, and we used to have a minimum set of data in `fields`. However, after upgrading to the latest version it is flattening the json data in `_source` and adding it to `fields`. Our `_source` json is pretty huge (containing array of arrays and array of objects) and because of this new feature, our kibana load times has significantly increased. Is there any way to disable this new feature.

**Edit**

I think this is happening because of a [feature](https://www.elastic.co/blog/discover-uses-fields-api-in-7-12) introduced since 7.12. This causes the increased load time of json view of data in kibana.

Adding an example of how the data used to look before and after the update. **Note**: I am posting a sample of how the data looks (not actual data). The schema of actual data is pretty large which includes multiple array of arrays and array of objects.

ELK 7.10.x data sample:

```
{
    "_index": "example-index",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "7b86b5e2e847b86b5e2e846b5e284",
    "_version": 6,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "locations": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    0,
                    10
                ],
                [
                    10,
                    20
                ]
            ],
            "type": "linestring"
        },
        "Id": "7b86b5e2e847b86b5e2e846b5e284",
        "@timestamp": "2022-02-02T00:38:41.423Z",
        "object": {
            "bbox": {
                "topleftx": 10,
                "bottomrighty": 300,
                "bottomrightx": 20,
                "toplefty": 200
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
            "2022-02-02T00:38:41.423Z"
        ]
    },
    "sort": [
        1643769673658
    ]
}
```

ELK 7.16.3 data sample:

```
{
    "_index": "example-index",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "7b86b5e2e847b86b5e2e846b5e284",
    "_version": 6,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "locations": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    0,
                    10
                ],
                [
                    10,
                    20
                ]
            ],
            "type": "linestring"
        },
        "Id": "7b86b5e2e847b86b5e2e846b5e284",
        "@timestamp": "2022-02-02T00:38:41.423Z",
        "object": {
            "bbox": {
                "topleftx": 10,
                "bottomrighty": 300,
                "bottomrightx": 20,
                "toplefty": 200
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": {
        "locations.coordinates": [
            0,
            10,
            10,
            20
        ],
        "Id.keyword": [
            "7b86b5e2e847b86b5e2e846b5e284"
        ],
        "Id": [
            "f2c2c45b656679825f7b86b5e2e847669edf37af"
        ],
        "locations.type.keyword": [
            "linestring"
        ],
        "locations.type": [
            "linestring"
        ],
        "@timestamp": [
            "2022-02-02T00:38:41.423Z"
        ],
        "object.bbox.toplefty": [
            200
        ],
        "object.bbox.topleftx": [
            10
        ],
        "object.bbox.bottomrighty": [
            300
        ],
        "object.bbox.bottomrightx": [
            20
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you ingesting data? I didn't notice any difference between 7.10 and 7.16.2

Comment: @dcolazin We have a couple of indices for which data gets inserted via REST Apis(Node.js) and few other indices for which the data gets inserted via Logstash. We are observing the new flattened fields when the data is inserted using both the methods.

Comment: are you using a json filter in logstash? because it will recursively parse json subobjects. can you post an example of data before/after the update?

Comment: @dcolazin I am using json filter in logstash, but it didn't cause any issue while running previous versions of logstash. If logstash was causing the issue then the same problem shouldn't appear when the document gets inserted via node.js rest apis, however it does appear. I am updating the question with example and some more details.